# Flutter как после appbar добавить два блока?

Tags: flutter

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить блок(container, row, column), после appBar. Подробнее на картинке:

[image: картинке]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто переместите `AppBar` в `body`:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
      Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
      AppBar(title: Text("Title"))
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Все просто, а я в дебри полез, свой appBar начала делать...Спасибо большой!